# How to Iterate over number of variadic template Types

Tags: c++

I'am currently learning C++ and i am currently building a very simple Entity Component System. For that i have a Function getComponentType which maps each Component to a
uint8_t. A Signature is just a std::bitset

I would like a method like this.

```
Signature signature = createSignature<TransformComponent, GraphicsComp>();
```

Lets say TransformComponent gets mapped to 0 and GraphicsComp get mapped to 1.
The Signature should now be a std::bitset {1100000...}
I know how to do that with non various template methods, the Question is now how would i archive the same with various template types or is there a better solution to do the same.

```
    template <typename T> Signature createSignature(){
        return Signature(((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<T>());
    }

    template <typename T, typename R> Signature createSignature(){
        return Signature(
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<T>() |
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<R>()
                );
    }

    template <typename T, typename R, typename S> Signature createSignature(){
        return Signature(
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<T>() |
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<R>() |
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<S>()
                );
    }

    template <typename T, typename R, typename S, typename U> Signature createSignature(){
        return Signature(
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<T>() |
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<R>() |
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<S>() |
                ((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<U>()
                );
    }
```

Comment: I could not really find a good title for this question any sugestions?

Comment: Instead of "various" did you mean ["variadic"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: yeah thanks just read up on it.

Comment: and to add more, apart from your title, may be you need to use "variadic" in your post as well for further clarification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From C++ 17 onward you could use a fold expression:

```
template<typename... T>
Signature createSignature()
{
   Return Signature((((unsigned long long int)1) << getComponentType<T>() | ...));
}
```

The unsigned long long int cast seems a bit weird, but I left it the same as the question to clarify the use of the fold expression:

```
(statement | ...)
```

The minimal version would look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
unsigned long long int stuffFor();

template<typename... T>
unsigned long long int variadicFoldedStuff() 
{
    return (stuffFor<T>() | ...);
}
```

Comment: Could be `1ULL`.

Comment: Wow that some nice syntax thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe variadic templates are the way to go here. Something along the lines of

```
template<typename T>
Signature createSignature(T t)
{
    return Signature(((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<T>());
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
Signature createSignature(T t, Args ...args)
{
    return Signature(((unsigned long long int)1)<<getComponentType<T>()) | createSignature(args...);
}
```

Comment: I think your comment just duplicates an already accepted solution.

Comment: A guy can only type so fast. Besides, the accepted version is the better way of doing it. Fold expressions make templates easier to deal with